# skipping "specific file extensions files" while moving all files with if condition statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I am writing a **bash script** which will move files/directories from existing directory path to another directory path. but I am not able to skip some extensions files while using `for loop` with `if condition` statements. My script is running without error but it wont skip the required extension files which I have specified in `if condition` instead it moves the all files and directories. below is the script I am trying to create for same.

please guide me where I am doing it wrong.

Below is what I am trying to do.

```
#!/bin/env bash

#moving home profile data to another location
echo "Moving Desktop Files"
path=/home/$USER/Desktop/*
for m in $path
do
      link=$(basename -s .lnk ${m})
      desktop=$(basename -s .desktop ${m})
      if [[  "${link}.lnk" == "${m}" ]] || [[ "${desktop}.desktop" == "${m}" ]]
      then
                echo "skipping link and desktop extension files"
                continue
      fi
mv -n "$m"  /home/$USER/CoreData/HOME/Desktop/

done
```

Comment: `rsync` has options to exclude files based on patterns such as name elements. Would that be an option? You would just need to remove the complete source files afterwards, as `rsync` is a tool to copy, not move.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , but my concern is about the script not the way to copy/move files . I am trying to skip files with some specific extensions as mentioned in script but when I execute the script all files are moves in to the specified path . why it is not skipping files with given extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching the filename suffixes in a very roundabout way, and you have written your loop in a way that disqualifies it from working on files with spaces in their names.

The main issue relating to your `if` statement is that `$m` is a pathname, containing directory path elements, while `$desktop` and `$link`, if interpreted as filenames, have no directory path elements.

Suggestions for safer code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for name in "$HOME/Desktop"/*; do
    if [[ $name == *.lnk ]] || [[ $name == *.desktop ]]; then
        printf 'Skipping "%s"\n' "$name"
    else
        mv -n -- "$name" "$HOME/CoreData/HOME/Desktop"
    fi
done
```

This uses (globbing) pattern matching with `==` within `[[ ... ]]` in `bash`.

If you really want to do the globbing of names separately and save them in a variable, then use an array for this:

```
names=( "$HOME/Desktop"/* )

for name in "${names[@]}"; do ... done
```

Note that the quoting above is important, to maintain the integrity of individual pathnames.

Or, using a `case ... esac` statement in `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for name in "$HOME/Desktop"/*; do
    case $name in
        *.lnk|*.desktop)
            printf 'Skipping "%s"\n' "$name"
            ;;
        *)
            mv -n -- "$name" "$HOME/CoreData/HOME/Desktop"
    esac
done
```

Again, would you want to do the globbing separately:

```
set -- "$HOME/Desktop"/*

for name do ... done
```

This uses the positional parameters rather than a named array.  The `sh` shell does not support named arrays.

Alternatively, use `rsync`:

```
rsync --archive --verbose \
    --exclude='*.lnk' \
    --exclude='*.desktop' \
    "$HOME/Desktop/" "$HOME/CoreData/HOME/Desktop"
```

(then remove `"$HOME/Desktop"` if you wish)

Comment: First of all thank you for the  solution & explanation  on my script. I have still one question if you don't mind. as you said **matching a file extension in very roundabout way** what that mean. second you said script will disqualify but I have one another script with little changes that works fine and this script also moves all the directories it has in ``$HOME/Desktop`` directory I am just curious to know why the ``continue`` command does not respond as condition is correct.

Comment: @ITGUYAKAY I mentioned this in my second paragraph. You are comparing something that is a filename (`$desktop` and `$link`) to something that is a filename with a directory path (`$m`).  The condition is therefore false and the `continue` statement is not executed.

Comment: got it   actually I didn't refresh the page. 